# Why is an edit that fixes typos in code inappropriate?

Tags: discussion

I was following @zeitesen's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216632/remote-notification-ios-8/24329372#24329372) question about iOS notifications. It was a helpful answer, but I noticed that the answer had some typos, both in the code and in the description. I edited the question and fixed the issues. [My edit was rejected with the following reason](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7139919):

"This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."

This feels incorrect to me though. I've fixed up messy questions and answers many times in the past, and it hasn't been an issue. Is it an issue because I changed the answer's code? I didn't change the logic or the intention - the original poster simply mistyped the names of a class and a method.

I made a second edit, thinking that maybe it was rejected because it wasn't thorough - there were a couple small typos remaining that I missed the first time. My change got rejected a second time for the same reason.

**What am I doing wrong?** Now when I look at the answer, the original poster implemented the *exact* same edits that I submitted. Why couldn't they have been accepted when I submitted them to begin with? As it is, it's giving me a disincentive to want to improve the site.

Comment: Your edits to the second snippet look to be fixing typos (and have since been edited by the author), your edits to the first snippet look to be incorrect edits, and the author has not changed them.

Comment: Thanks @Servy. I'm pretty sure the changes I made to the first snippet were actually correct - I made a comment on the answer now to let the original poster know.

Comment: Edits are there to improve the author's presentation of their own content.  If you think what they have provided is *wrong* you should be downvoting/commenting.  If you think that what they provided is correct, but they didn't express their answer clearly (like, say, because of a typo in which they meant to type the correct thing) then editing is fine.

Answer (score 10):

There's nothing wrong with fixing typos in code in **answers**. That code should be correct, however, you do need to be careful when making any changes to code that you don't make it worse.

There's everything wrong with fixing typos in code in **questions** as it may well be that it's those typos that are causing the problem.

It could be that those reviewing the edits were uncertain of this difference and erred on the side of caution by rejecting the edits. A safer option would be to leave a comment for the poster for them to fix it themselves.

Don't worry about it.